# Where to download binaries of coreutils?

Tags: binary

I'm trying to install some commands on an android device (namely `file` and a better version of `ls`), and I'm looking for the ARM binaries for it (namely the 5TE architecture) but I'm unable to find a place to download them. Googling things like "arm ls binary" or "ls binary" are giving me everything but what I want.

Is there a single place to find the binaries?

Comment: Have you looked into [crosscompiling your own?](https://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-arm-cross-compiling-howto.html)

Comment: Have you checked [BusyBox](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox)? It is available for android.

Comment: `file` is **not** part of GNU `coreutils`

Comment: @Bratchley I hadn't, but I might have to. @kirill-a I'll look into that. @Stephane I know, I was asking for `ls` in particular, and hoped there might be a place where all "low level" commands like that are kept

Answer (score 7):

The least painful way to install Linux utilities on an Android device is to install a whole distribution in a subdirectory. “Normal” distributions (Debian, Arch, Fedora, etc.) provide binaries that are dynamically linked with Glibc, which Android doesn't provide. They need to be executed with the loader (`/lib/ld-linux*.so`) of Glibc.

A simple way to set up such a system is to use Debian's [deboostrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) to build an initial Debian directory tree, transfer it to the Android device, and from then on install packages with `apt-get` and other standard Debian tools. There are a couple of pages on the topic on the Debian wiki: [ChrootOnAndroid](https://wiki.debian.org/ChrootOnAndroid), [HotwoDebianInAndroid](https://wiki.debian.org/HowtoDebianInAndroid).

1. First, install Debootstrap. On Debian or derivative, just install the `debootstrap` package. On some other Linux or other Unix variant, just grab the [debootstrap source tarball](https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/debootstrap) or check it out from Git: it's only a shell script and supporting data files.
2. Determine whether your device supports [hardware floating point](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort). If it doesn't, replace `armhf` by `armel` below. You can tell by checking `/proc/cpuinfo` under Android (or anything else using a Linux kernel): you must have ARMv7 (or ARMv8) with the features `thumbee` and `vfpv3`.
3. If you don't already have it, install [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.org/) on the Android device. While it isn't strictly necessary, it'll come handy below. You can retrieve the `busybox-static` Debian binary package, extract the BusyBox executable with `ar p busybox-static_*_armhf.deb data.tar.gz | tar -xzf - ./bin/busybox`, and transfer the `busybox` binary to the Android device. Below, I assume that BusyBox is located at `/vendor/bin/busybox`.
4. If your Android device is capable of mounting an SD card that's formatted as ext2/ext3/ext4 (or any other filesystem that supports unix permissions, i.e. not FAT), mount the SD card on your Unix PC and run the following command as root:

   ```
   debootstrap --arch=armhf --foreign wheezy /media/sdcard/debian http://http.debian.net/debian
   ```

   If not, run the following command as root (or under fakeroot, if you have it):

   ```
   sh -c 'debootstrap --arch=armhf --foreign wheezy /tmp/debian http://http.debian.net/debian && tar -zcf /tmp/debian.tar.gz -C /tmp debian'
   ```

   Now you need to transfer `/tmp/debian.tar.gz` to your Android device. You can do it over adb (`adb push /tmp/debian.tar.gz /`) or any other way that works for you, then unpack the tarball (use the BusyBox `tar`):

   ```
   tar -zxvf /debian.tar.gz
   ```
5. Set up a comfortable environment to run Linux programs. The easy way is to run them in a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). I assume that the Debian system is located at `/media/sdcard/debian` and that you have BusyBox. Create a shell script:

   ```
   #!/vendor/bin/busybox sh
   LINUX_ROOT=/media/sdcard/debian
   alias bb=/vendor/bin/busybox
   unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH SHELL
   export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
   # Bind-mount filesystems if not already done
   for d in /dev /media /proc /sys; do
     bb grep -q " $LINUX_ROOT$d " /proc/mounts || bb mount -o rbind "$d" "$LINUX_ROOT/$d"
   done
   for d in /data /system; do
     if ! bb grep -q " $LINUX_ROOT$d " /proc/mounts; then
       mkdir -p "$LINUX_ROOT/android/$d"
       bb mount -o rbind "$d" "$LINUX_ROOT/android/$d"
     fi
   done
   exec bb chroot "$LINUX_ROOT" /bin/bash "$@"
   ```

   Make this script executable and put it in `/vendor/bin` or anywhere else on the Android PATH. Before you can fully enjoy the Linux installation, you need to finish debootstrap's job: in the chroot, run

   ```
   /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
   ```

Answer (score 1):

While the GNU page does not seem to provide ARM binaries for the `coreutils` project, I managed to come across [this page](http://www.inreto.de/ffp/0.7/arm/PACKAGES.html#coreutils), which somehow provides compiled binaries for version 8.14.

- [coreutils-8.14-arm-1.txz](http://www.inreto.de/ffp/0.7/arm/packages/coreutils-8.14-arm-1.txz)

I downloaded it myself, and the `ls` binary provides the following metadata:

```
$ file ls
ls: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

Which should fit for an ARM system. Now, as Bratchley said, the best way is probably to compile `coreutils` for an ARM target. As far as I'm concerned, I compiled `coreutils` directly from an ARM system (Raspberry Pi, ARM6L), and all compatibility checks went fine.

Comment: Note that to run these binaries, you'll need Glibc, which Android doesn't provide.